# How to show some files at the top of the list in Ubuntu

Tags: filesystem

I want to name a folder so that it is displayed at top (first place) in Files (file manager) if the folders are sorted alphabetically by name.

With what to prefix the folder name in Ubuntu so that my folder is displayed at the top of the list in Files?

Comment: You should try with different symbols. Generally special characters and numbers are given higher preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nautilus sorts file names in this order:

1. special characters (`€`, `~`, `!`, etc)
2. numbers
3. alphabetic characters

Note that sorting by number means that a file named `30.txt` will appear before a file named `100.txt`. Read more details [here](http://muzso.hu/2013/09/16/nautilus-natural-filename-sorting).

Special characters mixed with alphabetic characters are treated as purely alphabetic strings and sorted among them (after numbers). However, the `.` character can be used after the prefix to overcome this issue: a folder/file named `€.aaaa` is listed before all files starting with numbers, whereas a folder/file named `€aaaa` is listed afterwards.

In my experience the most straightforward way is to simply use numbers.

Comment: I had tried special symbols, but it did not work. Names with specials characters prefix come  appear after files with number prefixed

Comment: If you mix special characters with alphabetic characters Nautilus will take it as a pure alphabetic string.

Comment: Take note that, "a@n" will be **after** "aaa". So, the guess about special character might not be right

Comment: the hint about using a "." is very helpful, thanks (I'm now prefixing some files with "_." to make bring them to the top of views in nemo/nautilus)

Comment: Where can I find a list that resolves the "etc" in your number one, special characters?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the standard C style sort order the sign with the lowest numeric value in the UTF-8 table that is on the keyboard is the exclamation mark.

See here http://unicode-table.com/en/

So I would suggest you try '!'.

As additional info: Under linux the setting of LC_COLLATE determines the sort order in general (even though that may depend on the implementation of the file manager that you are using). If '!' is not working for you try setting the LC_COLLATE variable to 'C' like so

```
LC_COLLATE=C ; export LC_COLLATE     # collate in strict numeric order
```

in you .bashrc for example.

Additional reading material can be found here:
http://teaching.idallen.com/net2003/06w/notes/character_sets.txt
or if you type `man sort` in a console to view the manpage of the sort utility.

Comment: Will not work for nautilus if you put it in your .bashrc, unless you then call nautilus by the command line. You need to edit `.profile`. And then, it will change **all** the collate of your accounts... in every command/application. For the environment variable thing, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Desktop_environment_specifics

Comment: True, but this info was only meant as additional info in case my basic answer (try '!') would not yield the expected result. Also Syed never said he was using nautilus.

Comment: the OP said it uses Files, with in the default Ubuntu installation is nautilus (see tags); moreover, the same would be valid for all desktop application --- .bashrc tweaking has effect only on terminals and programs launched from terminals.

Comment: @Rmano Please read the first word of my last comment again.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Files (aka `nautilus`) will sort in natural alphanumeric order (discussion omitted here), I would suggest calling your folders

```
1_Something 
2_Some_other_thing
[...]
```

I would advise against using special characters in the name, as `!` or spaces; you will be grateful when you will start to use the command line interface.

By the way, in Nautilus preferences (View tab) be sure to choose "sort folders before files" if you want to be on the safe side.

**Note** however that if you have a folder which name starts with `!` or a space it will be listed before the "numbered" ones.